# Organizing and create column names with values using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I would like to organize and create column names with values using Pandas

**Data**

```
name    Box     stat    size
dd1     HDL     FALSE   3
dd1     LDL     FALSE   3
dd2     LDL     FALSE   4
dd3     HDL     TRUE    1
dd5     HDL     FALSE   5
```

**Desired**

```
Box TRUE    FALSE   
HDL 1       8   
LDL 0       7
```

**Doing**

```
pivot_df = pd.pivot_table(df, values='size', index='Box', columns='stat', aggfunc=sum, fill_value=0)
```

However, the first column is not visible. Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I got your problem correct, just need to reset the index after creating the pivot table

```py
pivot_df = pd.pivot_table(df, values='size', index='Box', columns='stat', aggfunc=sum, fill_value=0)
pivot_df.reset_index(inplace=True)
```